# Android Default to Numeric Keypad with Option for QWERTY

Tags: android

Is it possible to have Android's numeric keypad display for an EditText (the one that would show with inputType="number"), while still having an option for users to switch back to the normal QWERTY keyboard?

My input field will usually be a number, but there will be times when text is necessary so I'd like to make it very easy to enter numbers, and extremely simple to switch over to entering text.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the sollution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can programatically change the keyboard being used by using the [setInputType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) method. So for instance, you could add a button in your UI that changes the input type from just pure numbers to a full on QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: Is it possible to do this on the keyboard itself?

Comment: I'd be interested if it can be switched from the keyboard too. Keeping the button that switches text and numeric on basic text keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should leave the button on the on-screen keyboard that lets you toggle between letters and numbers.

In xml, don't constrain the input--just leave it to the default of letters. (Not sure if this matters.)

```
mEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Unfortunately (on Android 3.1) when I set it up this way I do not see any option to switch back to the default keyboard.

Comment: Can you show your code and/or xml for creating the EditText? This works for me.

Comment: Never mind.  My code doesn't work for the stock Honeycomb keyboard either. It worked fine for a third-party keyboard. Could be a Honeycomb bug.